# How to flask know which python file to look at?

Tags: jquery, python, json, flask

I have just tried this example from [here](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/tree/master/examples/jqueryexample) which should show how jquery can send and get back data from a python function through Flask. I put them in the same directory and the index file would show up when i go to localhost but the calculation failed.

My problem is, where is the link between those files?? There is no mention of the python directory or even the python file name. I am a total newbie to flask and json. I tried to find some tutorials or samples but they just got me more confused.

How exactly this thing work?

```
@app.route('/_add_numbers')
```

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @youssefhassan raspberry pi raspbian.

Comment: @youssefhassan: whatever has this to do with the operating system Flask is running on?

Comment: What I understood from the question that he wants to setup the wsgi file to direct the apache to the project directory. Am I right?

Comment: @youssefhassan: no, that's not right. Flask doesn't necessarily run under Apache. Where did you get that idea from?

Comment: How are you running your Flask server, btw?

Comment: I think it is on Apache2? I'm not too sure about this... I don't even know if it is running. But i installed Apache2 on my Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 2):

The incoming URL includes a path:

```
http://example.com/path/on/your/server
```

where `example.com` is the hostname of your server and the `/path/on/your/server` section is matched against the routes you configured for your views.

```
@app.route('/_add_numbers')
def some_view():
    # do something, returning a string, a tuple, a response object or a WSGI app
```

matches the literal path `/_add_numbers` and nothing else; Flask will run that function.

Note that this does not route to any specific *file*, Flask is not like CGI where each path maps to a CGI script. You can still put your views into different Python modules, but that has not got anything to do with how Flask routes. As long as the `@app.route()` decorator was executed (registering the route and view function), Flask can find it again when a request comes in.

You can add in variable rules, where parts of the URL path matched can contain more than just fixed text:

```
@app.route('/user/<username>')
def show_user_profile(username):
    # show the user profile for that user
    return 'User %s' % username
```

Here the path can be any text after `/user/`, so `http://example.com/user/foobar` will result in the string `foobar` being passed to the `show_user_profile()` view.

You can read more about routing in the [Flask Quickstart](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#routing).

Comment: and in the case of that example, i have to add this? `a href=http://localhost/_add_numbers id=calculate>calculate server side</a>`

Comment: @yvonnezoe: exactly. Clicking on that link would tell the browser to load `http://localhost/_add_numbers` which leads to Flask being asked for that URL, which then matches `/_add_numbers` to the configured routes and finds that one view function.

Answer (score 0):

Flask uses mod wsgi of the apache,

You have to install the following packages if you don't have them already:

Tasksel
To install multiple packages at once
sudo apt-get install tasksel

Lamp-server
LAMP Server (Apache, MySQL)
sudo tasksel install lamp-server

Apache “mod_wsgi”
Enable the Apache module “mod_wsgi”
- sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi
- sudo a2enmode wsgi
- sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

Flask
Flask framework for implementing the RESTful webservices
sudo apt-get install python-pip
pip install Flask

then you have to add port for your website in the ports.conf:
sudo nano /etc/apache2/ports.conf

> NameVirtualHost *:5000
>
> Listen 5000

then create a new wsgi file that directs this port to your file:

```
<VirtualHost *:5000> 
    ServerName your_server_name

    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews ExecCGI 

    AddHandler wsgi-script .wsgi 


    WSGIDaemonProcess pmvc user=www-data group=www-data threads=5 
    WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/project/server.wsgi 

    <Directory /path/to/project/> 
        Allowoverride All 
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews ExecCGI 
        WSGIProcessGroup your_server_name 
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL} 
        Order deny,allow 
        Allow from all 
    </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```

then finally beside your python file where webservices are coded create server.wsgi file containing the following:

```
import sys

current_path = '/path/to/project'

if not current_path in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(current_path)

from your_python_file_name import app as application
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. How does **Flask** routing work? How does Flask know what view to invoke?

Comment: And note that Flask can run its own server (albeit only really suitable for development), and can run under any WSGI server. Where in the question does the OP ask about Apache, specifically?